# Proving that $E(Y_t)=0$ for an AR(1) process

Tags: statistics

I want to prove that for AR process:

$$Y_t=aY_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$$

Where $E(\epsilon_t)=0$ and $|a|<1$, that $E(Y_t)=0$

It's not assumed that there is such a thing as $Y(0)$ (in which case the proof would go through by induction).

It's trivial to prove by induction that:

$$E(Y_t) = a^n E(Y_{t-n})$$

And for any real number $b$: $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}a^n b=0$, which almost completes the proof.

I am left with proving that $E(Y_{t-n})$ doesn't grow with $n$, which would follow from $E(Y_t)=E(Y_{t-1})$. I am not sure how to prove this, should it be an axiom? I think some assumption is needed like with the finitistic case.

EDIT: It does seem like the above property or property that leads to it is just assumed. I would still very much like to see a formal proof / the axioms involved.

Answer (score 1):

As |a|<1, you can invert the process to give it its (infinite) moving average (MA) representation. Using the lag operator, $L^jx_t=x_{t-j}$, we have $(1-aL)Y_t =\epsilon_t$ and
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Y_t &=(1-aL)^{-1}\epsilon_t = (1+aL+a^2L^2 +a^3L^3 + \ldots )\epsilon_t \\
E(Y_t) &= (1+aL+a^2L^2 +a^3L^3 + \ldots )E(\epsilon_t) \\
 &=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Think that does it.

If you like you can go, as $|a|<1$, $Y_t$ is stationary. Hence $E(Y_t)=E(Y_{t-1}) =\mu_y$ (say). Hence $\mu_y = E(\epsilon_t)/(1-a) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, but I believe this counts as a circular proof, assumptions are baked into inversion of the lag operator.

Comment: That's a circular proof too ;). Also $|a|<1$...

Comment: Yes, thanks meant |a|<1. I really don't see the circularity problem you see. Generalise your process by adding a constant, c, to the rhs and you have E(Y_t)=c/(1-a). Then set c=0.

Comment: A process is stationary if $E(Y_t)=a$, that's what I am proving, just with the addition that $a=0$.

Comment: A process {$Y_t$} is (weakly) stationary if for all $t$, it's variance is finite, its mean is independent of $t$ and its covariance at two timepoints, $Cov(Y_t,Y_s)$, only depends on $t-s$. For your AR(1), $Var(Y) = Var(\epsilon)/(1-a^2)$, $Cov(Y_t,Y_s)=a^{t-s}Var(Y)$ and (as explained) $E(Y)=0$.

Comment: I am asking for foundational proof, listing higher level properties doesn't really help with that, as they are proven using this property.

Comment: In that case, I misunderstood your aim. Knowing about square summable processes and their convergence will help here. I really should have simply directed you to the excellent book "Introduction to Statistical Time Series" (2nd ed) by W.A. Fuller.  Sections 2.2 and 2.3 should give you all you need.

Comment: I took a look at the book and it seems that the author assumes that for all $n$ $Y_n$ is less than some limiting value. That is what I wanted to prove.

Comment: This is in danger of becoming a chat (apparently). I think, all you need is to confirm what you are assuming re $\epsilon_t$ as repeated substitution for $Y_{t-i}$ gives you an infinite MA. Zero mean, finite and constant variance and uncorrelated is typical and enough to conclude $E(Y_t)=0$ in probability. Don't mean to throw another reference at you but Hamilton (Time Series Analysis) explains on pages 52-53 and Appendix 3A. Not inconsistent with Fuller but you may prefer his style.